# python open(): [Errno 13] Permission denied: / Pandas read_csv: File does not exist - but file exists

Tags: python, ubuntu, pandas

*I'm running a website with python 2.7 on an ubuntu server.*

I have been using pandas read_csv() for months without fail.  However, I made some change last night (I guess, can't think of any other reason) that is now throwing up errors when I try the same function and I'm dead in the water.  My code typically looks something like this:

```
my_file = '/var/www/site/folder/test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(my_file, header = 0)
```

That has worked for me since day 1, yesterday, it stopped working.  It now throws the error:

```
File /var/www/site/folder/test.csv does not exist
```

So, I then tried:

```
my_file = '/var/www/site/folder/test.csv'
df = open(my_file, 'r')
```

And now I'm getting:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/site/folder/test.csv'
```

So those two errors themselves are a contradiction, but whatever.  I then looked at the permissions: 777.  So that shouldn't be an issue.

The file exists, clear as day as verified through:

- WinSCP
- `ls` in the ubuntu command line
- `os.listdir()` in python

Anyone have any ideas on why these errors are suddenly coming up and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Your script probably runs from another user, not the one you're checking file from, that would explain unability to re-produce. You should probably also check if your user has permission to read and execute `/var/www/site/folder` directory.

Comment: The file shows when running os.listdir() by the same user and I've dialed up all access as liberally as I thought I could.  Maybe I'm just not familiar enough with file access.  Can you provide guidance on how to check user permission?  Thanks.

Comment: And to reiterate, I've been doing this exact same thing with many many files with the same user for six months with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: What are the permissions on each folder leading up to the file?

Comment: If the script really executes with the same EUID and EGID (effective user and group ids) you verify the file's existence, then it really doesn't make sense. Could your script's privileges be lowered when run (a common scheme for webservers: start as root, then drop to `www-data` or `nginx` user)? As for guidance, you should check that every directory in path (`/var`, `/var/www` etc) has both read and execute permissions for your user. Long story short, execute permission for a directory means you can `chdir` to it, and read means you can read its contents.

Comment: As another user mentioned (he removed the comment), you also may get your UID/GID from inside the script with `os.getuid()`,`os.getgid()` functions and log the result somewhere. That could help with debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  It was the permissions leading up to the file that was the issue.  However, all users had "read" permission, it was the "execute" permission I had to change despite the fact that I was simply reading from the .csv.  Any reason why that may be?

Comment: Maybe it was a bad recursive `chmod`, or something's clumsy installator, or something else. About 'despite' part, once again, you have to have execute permissions all the way up to a file to be able to traverse through directory hierarchy.

Comment: Good to know re: the "execute" permission to get to a file - thanks again.